# how to load landing page in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to show landing page in my app like linkedin. When you open the app then first show logo of the app means user can't see [blank page](http://screencast.com/t/fUPYEaQgWp) or until app loaded user see logo of the app. I not know how to do this. Can some one provide sample code or any helpful link

Comment: provide splash image  http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/cordova-ios-splash-screen/  check http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-splash-screen-in-your-ios-app/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a launch image for your app in xcode.

It's really easy, look here for more info:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html